# Parsing DNS info to .txt file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, dns, txt

I need to get the DNS info, which can be found under ipconfig /all but when I try it using

```
SETLOCAL
(

FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%b IN ('ipconfig /all') DO (
 
FOR /f %%t IN ("%%b") DO (
  
If /i "%%t"=="DNS" ECHO %%c&GOTO done
 )

)
)> out.txt
```

it gives me the DNS suffix. Any suggestions on how I might actually get DNS servers? If I try with

```
If /i "%%t"=="DNS" ECHO %%c&GOTO done
```

then I end up with no info at all. I'm using a batch file and cmd

Answer (score 0):

```batch-file
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
set "dnsserverlines="
(
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%b IN ('ipconfig /all') DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1,2" %%t IN ("%%b") DO (
 IF DEFINED dnsserverlines IF "%%c" neq "" GOTO :EOF 
 IF DEFINED dnsserverlines IF "%%t" neq "0.0.0.0" ECHO  %%t 
 If /i "%%t%%u"=="DNSServers" ECHO %%c&set "dnsserverlines=Y"
 )
)
)> out.txt
GOTO :EOF
```